# No funciona Search Delegate con Firebase Flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter

Estoy intentando usar un Search Delegate en mi app de flutter, pero al ejecutarlo y escribir algo en la barra solo se queda cargando y no muestra ningun resultado sobre el listado de "participantes", aqui el codigo del boton que va hacia la pantalla:

```
        Widget _botonBusqueda() {
      return FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "buscar",
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: (){
          showSearch(context: context, 
            delegate: DataSearch(),
          );
        },
      );
    }
```

Y aqui el codigo dentro del search delegate:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:timing_ready/src/models/evento_model.dart';
    import 'package:timing_ready/src/providers/eventos_provider.dart';

    class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate{

    final eventosProvider = EventosProvider();
    EventoModel evento =  EventoModel();
    Participantes participantes =  Participantes();

      @override
      List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
        // Acciones del AppBar
        return [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: () {
              query = " ";
            },
          )
        ];
      }

      @override
      Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
        // Icono a la izquierda del AppBar
        return IconButton(
          icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
            progress: transitionAnimation,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            close(context, null);
          },
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
        // Builder de los resultados
        return Container();
      }

      @override
      Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
        // Sugerencias al escribir
        if ( query.isEmpty ) {
          return Container();
        }

        return FutureBuilder<List<Participantes>>(
          future: eventosProvider.buscarParticipantes(evento, participantes),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final participantes = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: participantes.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) { 
                  return _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i]);
                }
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
      Widget _crearParticipante(BuildContext context, Participantes participantes) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('${participantes.apellido}',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            softWrap: true,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: "Lato_LightItalic",
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Text('Numero: ${ participantes.numero }',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: "Lato_LightItalic",
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontSize: 16.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

    }
```

El Future de "buscar participantes" lo deje asi:

```
         Future<List<Participantes>> buscarParticipantes( EventoModel evento, Participantes participantes ) async {

        final url = "$_url/eventos/${ evento.id }/participantes.json";
        final resp = await http.get(url);
        final respBody = json.decode(resp.body) as List;
        final participantes = respBody;
        return participantes;

      }
```

El listado de los participantes si me carga en la pagina anterior, pero al querer hacer la busqueda esta no funciona, estos datos los cargo de una base de datos de firebase que me los envia en un archivo .json

Comment: el FutureBuilder no se vuelve a crear, te recomiendo crear una clase `bloc` que maneje la lógica del negocio, ahí puedes realizar la carga asincrona y luego notificar a los widgets